how to pre-fill an fields for authentication method on the swagger or test it interactive api using drf spectacular?
i need to pre-filled fields like username, password for authentication on drf spectacular
i'm using the schema and the auth,and i need to pre fill the fields like :
username:text, password:text
but i didn't find any document for that:
"auth": [{"Api-Key Auth": []}, {"Basic Auth": []}, {"JWT Auth": []}],

i've tried to add on the auth like this, but still can see the fields empty:
class KeycloakBasicAuthExtension(OpenApiAuthenticationExtension):
    target_class = "contrib.keycloak.auth.KeycloackBasicAuth"
    name = "Basic Auth"
    priority = 1
    match_subclasses = True

    def get_security_definition(self, auto_schema):
        return {
            "type": "http",
            "scheme": "basic",
            "x-example": {"username": "test", "password": "test"},
        }

and even i've tried to add n Request Name on the schema, but i can still see the Request Name when deploy to the gitbook as None:
class CheckoutSchema(ModelSchema):
    view_class = CheckoutCreateApiView
    post = {
        "summary": "Create a new Payment Transaction",
        "description": "Create a new Payment Transaction",
        "tags": [
            "Checkout API",
        ],
        "operation_id": "create_payment_transaction_checkout",
        "methods": ["POST"],
        "request": get_checkout_serializer(name="CheckoutPOSTRequestSerializer"),
        "responses": {
            201: get_checkout_serializer(name="CheckoutPOSTResponseSerializer"),
            400: PolymorphicProxySerializer(
                component_name="ClientErrors",
                serializers=[
                    serializers.FieldErrorSerializer,
                    serializers.NestedFieldErrorSerializer,
                    serializers.GenericErrorMessage,
                ],
                resource_type_field_name=None,
            ),
            401: serializers.GenericErrorMessage,
            403: serializers.GenericErrorMessage,
            404: serializers.GenericErrorMessage,
            415: serializers.GenericErrorMessage,
            423: serializers.GenericErrorMessage,
        },
        "examples": [
            OpenApiExample(
                "Create Payment Transaction Example",
                summary="create a new payment transaction request example",
                description="This example demonstrates how to send a complete request to create a payment transaction.",
                value={
                    "amount": "1.000",
                    "currency_code": "KWD",
                    "pg_codes": get_default_pg_codes(),
                    "type": "payment_request",
                },
                request_only=True,
            ),
        ],
        "auth": [{"Api-Key Auth": []}, {"Basic Auth": []}, {"JWT Auth": []}],
    }

